# Getting too many notifications in Trello

Tags: trello, trello-organization, trello-boards

I'm getting alerts for every action that is taken on Trello boards I am a member of, even when I am not a member on the card, nor have I been `@ed` in the comments.

The downside of getting so many notifications is that when I get card / notification that is to do with me it gets lost in the sea of other irrelevant notifications.

Ive checked if I am subscribed to the boards (as I understand this would give me all notifications) but I am not subscribed.

Some of these boards belong to a Trello organisation I'm an admin of (not sure if that would have something to do with it?)

Is there a way I can set my account to only give me notifications when I am either a member on the card in question or @ed in the comments of that card?

Similarly in the iOS mobile app (screenshot below) there is an option to view the notification that are for 'Me', can this be set as the default for all the notifications - email, web, mobile?

[image: trello app ios screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this link helps [Understanding Notifications in Trello](http://www.looksgoodworkswell.com/understanding-notifications-in-trello/).

Key Points from the article:

Request the right amount of notifications

1. Unsubscribe from all boards. This was a big mistake on my part. I had subscribed to the board itself. This created an enormous amount of noise and was why I ended up turning all notifications off and led to me missing the power of trello notications.
2. Subscribe only to cards that you really want notifications on. Remember you will get pinged every time that card moves to another list or any action happens on the card. Make sure you want that to happen.
3. Assign yourself to a card only when you are really responsible for the card. Don’t use this as a means for getting notifications. That is what subscribe is used for. Remember, notification is a by-product of assigning yourself to a card or being assigned to a card.

Answer (score 0):

You can change how often you get notification emails in your "Account" page. You can also can set your notification email preferences by clicking the **Notifications button** in the header and selecting **"Change Your Notification Frequency"**.

Options are:

- Never
- Periodically
- Instantly

**Instantly"** is the default and any unread notifications in Trello are emailed out as soon as possible. We suspect at present your settings was in instant mode. You can change to **never** to stop this notification

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this relates to the email notifications rather than the web app and mobile notifications, in fact the email notifications seem to be just relevant to me rather than every activity, which is what im looking for for the web app and mobile app.